A somewhat cumbersome recursive convergence questions
I would like to have my solution reviewed  and a question regarding the format of the question, I felt like question one is redundant. Instead of showing that $\forall{x_n}, x_n>\sqrt{5}$ can I simply pick an arbitrary lower bound lets say 0, and then I show it is monotone which enables me to calculate limit directly. I felt its doable, but if I do that during Real analysis exam, will I receive full points for the question or not? The cumbersome structure consume more a lot of time.
Anyway here’s the solution of mine:
Given recursive relation: $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(x_n+\frac{5}{x_n}\bigg)$
(i) Show that $x_n>\sqrt{5}$, $\forall{n}\in{\mathbb{N}}$
(ii) Determine wether the sequence $x_n$ is monotone.
(iii) Show if the limit exists, if yes then compute the limit
Answer (i)
Claim that for all $n\in{\mathbb{N}}, \ x_n>\sqrt{5}$
Base case for $n=1$ we have $x_1=5=\sqrt{5}^2>\sqrt{5}$ holds true.
Assume for some arbitrary $n>1$ the statement is proven such that we have:
\begin{equation}
    2x^2_{n}=\bigg(x_{n-1}+\frac{5}{x_{n-1}}\bigg)^2>20
\end{equation}
Inductive step:
\begin{equation}
  x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(x_n+\frac{5}{x_{n}}\bigg)
\end{equation}
Algebraic manipulation: $4x^2_{n+1}= \bigg(x_n+\frac{5}{x_n}\bigg)^2$ by induction hypothesis:
\begin{equation}
    4x^2_{n+1}> \bigg(10+\frac{5}{x_n}\bigg)^2 
\end{equation}
Then it follows: $x^2_{n+1}>\frac{1}{4}\bigg(x_n+\frac{5}{x_n}\bigg)^2>\frac{10^2}{4}$
Implying:
\begin{equation}
    x_{n+1}>\frac{5}{2}>\sqrt{5} \text{   Arithmetic-Geometric Inequality}
\end{equation}
(ii)
\begin{equation}
    x_{n+1}-x_{n}=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(x_{n}+\frac{5}{x_{n}}\bigg)-x_{n}=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{5}{x_{n}}-x_{n}\bigg)<0
\end{equation}
Implying $\forall{n\in{\mathbb{N}}} \Rightarrow x_{n+1}<x_n$
(iii) Define: $A:=\{x_n | n\in{\mathbb{N}}\}$.
Since $x_n$ is monotone and decreasing, it is clear that it is bounded above by $5$ which we want to show that $A$ is bounded below:
We claim for the sake of contradiction that there exist some $x'_n \in{A}$ such that $x'_n<0$ then it follows $x'_{n+1}>x'_{n}$
This leads to contradiction of the monotonicity of our derivation earlier as it shows the contradictory outcome.
This implies $A$ is bounded below, and by the monotone convergent theorem (2.4.3) we know the sequence converges, by axiom of completeness we know there is an infimum for $A$ As $n$ tends sufficiently large the distance between $x_n$ is arbitrary close to the infimum.
Let: $l=x_n=x_{n-1}$ it follows that:
\begin{equation}
    l=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(l+\frac{5}{l}\bigg)
\end{equation}
By rearrangement:
\begin{equation}
     l^2-5=0
 \end{equation}
Since we have reasoned that $x_n>0$ it follows: $\lim{x_n}=\sqrt{5}$
\end{document}

To your first point: yes, it would be sufficient to show that the sequence is eventually monotone and bounded regardless of what the bounds are. Note that if $x_1=1$ then the sequence is not monotone but eventually monotone. However, I think this series of questions is trying to lead you towards a specific way of thinking  and if you choose to go a different route don't be surprised if you don't get full points. Second, your proof is incorrect. Note that in your induction proof you have proved that $x_1=5>\frac{5}{2}$ and that $x_{n+1}>\frac{5}{2}$. Since the limit is supposed to be $\sqrt{5}$, you have clearly made an error somewhere. A correct proof:
i) Clearly $\sqrt{5}<5=x_1$. Suppose by way of contradiction that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n+1}\leq \sqrt{5}$. Without loss of generality, we may as well assume that this $n$ is minimal (ie for any $m<n+1$ we have $x_m>\sqrt{5}$). Then
$$5\geq x_{n+1}^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(x_n^2+10+\frac{25}{x_n^2}\right)$$
$$0\geq x_n^2+10+\frac{25}{x_n^2}-20$$
$$0\geq x_n^2-10+\frac{25}{x_n^2}$$
$$0\geq \frac{(x_n^2-5)^2}{x_n^2}$$
However, this is a contradiction since we know $x_n^2>5$. We conclude $x_{n+1}>\sqrt{5}$ for all $n$.
ii) For this part, your equation is correct but you might want to add some details about why
$$\frac{5}{x_n}-x_n<0$$
Its clearly true, but depending on a grader you might lose points. One way to clear this up would be
$$0=\frac{5-5}{x_n}>\frac{5-x_n^2}{x_n}=\frac{5}{x_n}-x_n$$
iii) Your reasoning is correct, but there is no need to show $x_n>0$ since you have already shown $x_n>\sqrt{5}>0$ in part i). I would also clean up your notation: it is sloppy to say $l=x_n=x_{n-1}$. Instead, write
$$l=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{5}{x_n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(l+\frac{5}{l}\right)$$
$$l=\frac{1}{2}\left(l+\frac{5}{l}\right)$$
$$l\in\{-\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5}\}$$
Since $l>0$ we conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=\sqrt{5}$.
